# toshiba satellite keyboard not working correctly

Tags: keyboard, keys, toshiba-satellite

The first letter in the alphabet `a` is not working on my keyboard. I'm also noticing that the num lock light flashes with every keystroke of any letter as I type.  I re-installed an older version of Ubuntu and it works again so it is the 11.10 release of Ubuntu.

How can I fix this?

model is toshiba satellite l655d-s5076rd

Comment: Run `xev` from a gnome-terminal and then press the `a` key and add the output to your question.

Comment: PropertyNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    atom 0x1a8 (_NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY), time 21240586, state PropertyNewValue

Comment: That's all? Can you try again with `xev > xev.log`, then press `a`, then close the little window, open xev.log, copy its content to http://paste.ubuntu.com and add the link here?

Comment: It hd wy more but it ws 4000 chrters too long for  comment.  I will do it gin but, is there something specific you re looking for since this is so limited.  I hve  mx of 500 chrcters

Comment: Just use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ to paste it. I'm looking for something like [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/717361/).

Comment: OK, I put the text on my blog.  http://carlcordellphotoblog.blogspot.com/

Comment: Done http://paste.ubuntu.com/717368/

Comment: Ok, so the key press doesn't even show up. Does the 'a' work if you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 (you can go back to the desktop with Ctrl+Alt+F7)? Anyways, I really think this should better be a bug report as I don't see how we can help you with such a weird problem. To report it, run `ubuntu-bug linux` and follow the instructions. Don't forget to add all the information you have (like that it works with previous versions of Ubuntu). More [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I reported the bug with Ubuntu.  The key will not respond t ll even with ctrl, etc.  It works fine with the older version so I'm going to reinstll the old version nd sty wy from this one.  It's clerly not comptible with my lptop.  Thnks for giving it  shot.  I'm seeing others posting problems s well so 11.10 hs bugs I'm not up for deling with.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Comment: @jrg I don't think the OP can really flag. He has 15 rep. Or am I mistaken? I'm just asking about a general case.